# How can I either compare from another list and negate those on that list or do a if statement to skip something inside a file

Tags: perl

I have 2 files one which has these items, the other file call compare has 1 of those which is "SF-Arecibo" I want to skip this one from the program.

Bielsko-Biala-PL-Cluster
SF-Bonn-Germany-Cluster
SF-Bosconero-Cluster
SF-Brampton-CA-Cluster
CLEOHECLABCP1
SF-Arecibo
SF-Dublin-IE-Cluster
SF-JiningCN-Cluster
SF-KingsMountainNC-Cluster
SF-Lenexa-KS-US
SF-New-York-US
SF-Rockville-MD-US
SF-VanWert-OH-US

`

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;


{

    my $file = '/var/log/scripts/clusters_ips.txt';
    my $batch_size = 20;
    my @batches;
    
 {
        open (my $info, '<', $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";

        chomp(my @clusters = <$info>);
        close $info;
        my @targets;
        @batches = split_into_batches($batch_size, @clusters);
    }
    for my $batch (@batches) {
        my @clusters = @$batch;
        my @targets;
        for my $i (0..$#clusters) {
            my $cluster = $clusters[$i];
        if (@clusters !~ /^SF-Arecibo/){

            my $tind = $i + 1;
            push @targets, "targets.$tind", "\"$cluster\"";

                print  @targets;
                print @clusters;
        }
      ##  system 'mgmt_cli', '-r', 'true', 'install-policy', 'policy-package', '"Site-Firewalls"',
      ## 'access', 'false', 'threat-prevention', 'true', @targets;
}
   }

}
`
```

Comment: *"file call compare has 1 of those which is "SF-Arecibo" I want to skip this"* : So this file only has a single line which contain the text  "SF-Arecibo" ? Why is your script is not attempting to read this file then?

Comment: I have another file name exceptions_clusters.txt
with these ones:
CLEOHECLABCP1
SF-Arecibo
SF-Dublin-IE-Cluster
SF-JiningCN-Cluster
SF-KingsMountainNC-Cluster
SF-Lenexa-KS-US
SF-New-York-US
SF-Rockville-MD-US
SF-VanWert-OH-US
the goal is to run program and when it his this list skip those

Comment: *"the goal is to run program and when it hit this list skip those"* : So then the script should read this file `exceptions_clusters.txt` first?

Comment: correct 2 files one clusters_ips.txt it has all the Clusters second file exceptions_clusters.txt has the clusters that it should not run the program

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can skip clusters from the `exceptions_clusters.txt` file in the batch processing. You read those exceptions into a hash, that you can later pass into the `split_into_batches()` sub to skip those clusters from the batches:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    my $file = '/var/log/scripts/clusters_ips.txt';
    my %exceptions = read_exception_clusters('exceptions_clusters.txt');
    my $batch_size = 20;
    my @batches;
    {
        open (my $info, '<', $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";
        chomp(my @clusters = <$info>);
        close $info;
        my @targets;
        @batches = split_into_batches($batch_size, \%exceptions, @clusters);
    }
    for my $batch (@batches) {
        my @clusters = @$batch;
        my @targets;
        for my $i (0..$#clusters) {
            my $cluster = $clusters[$i];
            my $tind = $i + 1;
            push @targets, "targets.$tind", "\"$cluster\"";
        }
        system 'mgmt_cli', 'install-policy', 'policy-package', '"Site-Firewalls"',
           'access', 'false', 'threat-prevention', 'true', @targets;
    }
}

sub read_exception_clusters {
    my $fn = shift;

    open (my $fh, "<", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    chomp(my @exceptions = <$fh>);
    close $fh;
    my %exceptions = map {$_ => 1} @exceptions;
    return %exceptions;
}

sub split_into_batches {
    my $batch_size = shift;
    my $exceptions = shift;
    my @clusters = @_;
    my @batches;
    my $j = 1;
    my $idx = 0;
    for my $cluster (@clusters) {
        next if exists $exceptions->{$cluster};
        if ($j > $batch_size) {
            $j = 1;
            $idx++;
        }
        push @{$batches[$idx]}, $cluster;
        $j++;
    }
    return @batches;
}
```